# How to Normalize a feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-scaling

I have a feature that income of individual. It ranges from 10k to 116 Million. I have about 300k+ records.

Clearly, I cannot use this feature as is as it will distort the model output and there are outliers..

I was thinking of normalizing all values from 0 to 1. And also eleminating outliers. Like if most values from from 30k to 200k, then people with income of 200k would get a score around 1.

I have 2 questions?
1) Is this approach reasonable or should I think about it differently.
2) and suggestions on how to normalize and/or scale values to avoid outliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with many ideas, but wether they are going to be useful depends on what you are building:

- Take the logarithm of the variable, and use that as a feature, and then you can normalize it or work with it.
- Transform it into a categorical variable using its deciles/quartiles.
- Crop the very high values to the 95th percentile, and the normalize it.

I fancy specially the second one, as I really like tree-based methods and it shines in these methods.

Comment: Thanks David. I am going to try first one. I have not decided which algorithm to use yet. I am reviewing each feature and making it usable at the moment. I already tried second one and it was kind of interesting too but when I look at grouped summary, I couldn't derive any conclusion and so i think log will add more value.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is rather common. I think you might want to consider the distribution of your data and whether you want to do anything with your outliers. Some popular normalization techniques: `min-max` and `z-score`. You will see tons of resources by googling them. From the limited amount of time I work with income data, sometimes you might want to test with a log scale as well as the top 1%-ers tend to skew the normalization as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the distribution of the income will be a power law distribution. But I think the one that you should worry most is not the input features but the output since the output has a direct influence in your model while the input features effects are not yet certain. And do not just eliminate the outliers, study the distribution of the features (especially the output) first.

I think the power law is distribution is a powerful beast to be tamed in Machine Learning. This might encourage multi-model approach for each scale but I will try something like making features like these: example (116,299,900): Million <- 116 Thousands <- 299 Ones <- 900. Millions, Thousands and Ones are the new features. Then I will will apply normalization for each feature.